# c# Chart, how to add label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

I am new to System.Web.Helpers.Chart .
I try to generate report and display using chart.

Below is my code that i use to generate one of my report

```
public ActionResult columnChartForECNWithoutECO()
    {
        ArrayList xValueDraft = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList xValueWithoutECO = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();
        SAMMeerkatECCSDataAccess dataAccess = new SAMMeerkatECCSDataAccess();
        System.Data.DataTable results = dataAccess.reportGetECNWithoutECOByUser();

        foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
        {

            xValueDraft.Add(row["Draft"].ToString());
            xValueWithoutECO.Add(row["WithoutECO"].ToString());
            yValue.Add(row["userName"].ToString());
        }

        var key = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Vanilla)
           .AddTitle("Total ECN Without ECO By User").AddLegend("Details")
           .AddSeries
           (

               chartType: "Column",
               xValue: yValue,
               yValues: xValueDraft, 
               axisLabel: "Bar 1",
               name: "ECO Draft"
           )
           .AddSeries(
           chartType: "Column",
            axisLabel: "Bar 2",
           xValue: yValue,
           yValues: xValueWithoutECO,
           name: "Without ECO"
           );



        return File(key.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");

    }
```

and the result i get is this

[image]

May I know how can I show the number of value on every bar column as highlighted in the image ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 250)
        .AddSeries(
            ...)
        .AddSeries(
            ...)
        .AddLegend();  //Add this
```

Also try to use below code to add more specific control to the legend:

```
chart.Series["Data"].Label = "#PERCENT{P0}";
chart.Series["Data"].Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.0f, FontStyle.Bold);
chart.Series["Data"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
chart.Series["Data"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
chart.Series["Data"].Legend = "Stores";
chart.Legends["Stores"].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your reply.. I tried your first suggestion which is 'AddLegend()', but unfortunately it not working.
Then i try to use second method, error show me that 'Chart' doesnt contain the definition of 'Series' an no extension method for this.
May I know why ?

Comment: not Chart, but chart! Note your variable name, you have to replace it with your own naming.

Comment: Is this answer using the desktop version of charting (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Appear to be, the web version does not have .Series method